Intra cloud lightning cloud atsworth in durban south africa , ..1st time ever to see such
Intra cloud lightning  cloud to cloud  lightning that continued for over an hour over Chatsworth in durban south africa , this is the 1st time to witness someso phenomenal....we could sleep but to stop and stare at the clouds and to see such images lit up inside the clouds ....it was light Christmas lights and its Christmas week    diffantely end times message JESUS is coming soon halelujha

Intra cloud lightning is the most common type of lightning on our planet,clod to ground strikes are about 10% and the rest is cloud to cloud or intra cloud strikes. https://www.rmets.org/metmatters/types-lightning
